# Pull hi res image from reddit API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, reddit

I have a simple script to fetch images from a sub-reddit:

The only issue is that it's pulling the low res thumbs instead of the high res image.

```
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/RoomPorn.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => res.data.children)
  .then(res => res.map(post => ({
    author: post.data.author,
    link: post.data.url,
    img: post.data.thumbnail,
})))

.then(res => res.map(render))
.then(res => console.log(res))

const app = document.querySelector('#app');

const render = post => {
const node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = `
  <a href="${post.link}">
    <img src="${post.img}"/>
  </a>`;
app.appendChild(node);
}
```

Is it possible to pull the high res instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/RoomPorn.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => res.data.children)
  .then(res => res.map(post => ({
    author: post.data.author,
    link: post.data.url,
    img: post.data.preview.images[0].source.url,
})))
```

btw post.data.url should be the high res image link from original source.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.

I tried your script:

https://jsfiddle.net/7f0zyp3z/3/

But it fails to fetch, any ideas?

Comment: @kathrynm you forgot to call your render method in this jsfiddle. try: https://jsfiddle.net/7f0zyp3z/5/